# Intercepting session creation spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to have some object in my view but I don't want to repeat/include code in each method in my Controller so instead I thought to put this object in a session.

This way it can be available in view and I don't repeat code.

So my question is how to intercept form creation and set some object to every session created?

Comment: You could use a Servlet filter but getting Spring instantiated beans into filters in a PITA.

Comment: I've dealt with this problem in the past by simply putting the code that adds the various objects into the model, into a regular method (with a single arg: Model) and then reference this method in each controller method that needs it. This adds one line per controller method and means the code is easy to grok for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to make some data/object available to all of your controller methods, better put that in Model at controller's method level (using @ModelAttribute). Example below:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{

    @ModelAttribute
    public void getEmpRoles(Model model) {
        List<String> roles = myservice.loadEmpRoles();
        model.addAttribute(roles);
    }

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public String m1(Model model){
        // You roles model is available here
    }
}
```

See spring doc here(http://bit.ly/JCutg2) to know more about @ModelAttribute at method level